# How do I change form data on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the case of text entered into a textbox for a search when the form is submitted. I'm having an issue when it comes to submitted the converted text. Using the code below, how can I submit the form with the converted text? I would prefer that the appearance of the text in the text box is not altered.

```
search.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    convert = searchBox.val();
    converted = convert.toTitleCase();

    this.submit();
});
```

Comment: Answered your edit in my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
search.submit(function (e) {
  searchBox.val(searchBox.val().toTitleCase());
});
```

Comment: this answer is more concise.. but to make it even more, remove the preventDefault and submit altogether

Comment: Is there a way to submit the converted text without altering the appearance of the text box?

Comment: Thanks! Removed preventDefault and submit :)

Comment: You can either create a new form and modify the values, or take the name attribute off of the input of the unconverted text and save it to a hidden input with the name attribute that you want used and set the value to the converted text. I'll update my answer with that.

Answer (score 2):

You are converting the text, but you're not saving it back to the input before you submit.

Try something like this:

```
search.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    convert = searchBox.val();
    converted = convert.toTitleCase();
    $('#inputID').val(converted);

    this.submit();
});
```

And I don't believe you need to `preventDefault` and then `submit`.. just return true.

EDIT: Per your question in the above answer's comment, try this:

original:
`<input type=text name="myinput" id="myinput">`

new:

html

```
<input type=text id="myinput">

<input type=hidden name="myinput" id="myinputHidden">
```

jscript

```
search.submit(function (e) {
    $('#myinputHidden').val($('#myinput').val().toTitleCase());
});
```

The `name` attribute is what the form uses to create it's POST/GET parameters ... if the name attribute doesn't exist, the form doesn't send the value

Answer (score 1):

```
convert = searchBox.val();
converted = convert.toTitleCase();
searchBox.val(converted);
```

Comment: It should be searchBox.val(converted)

Comment: jquery tag in the Q, so it's safe to assume they are